# batch find file, replace with another file, that is supplied

Tags: batch-file, replacewith

I need help creating a batch file to find multiple files named the same thing in 100's of files and replace the with a different file...

Alternatively, is there a program that will do this if I select the 2 different files that will search and replace them...

1. Find file from computer Pairing = `High School DxD - Kuroka.png`
2. Replace file with Pairing = `High School DxD - Kuroka (F).jpg`

Comment: The term "helping" implies that you do something on your own rather than just requesting code for free. Please share your efforts by providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Also read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Changing the file extension does not change the type of file; are you sure you aren't wishing to convert a file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you never provided the basic information such as `What directory you wish to start a search from` or `You wish to convert or just rename`, I will assume you wish to search your photo's folder (Including sub-directories) and simply rename file.jpg to file.png.

To search photo's and all its directories we can use the `FOR /R` to search for all `.jpg` files and `DO` to address the action. The script bellow will do the following.

- Search and replace all `.jpg` extensions to `.png` in the **photo** folder directory

**Batch Script:**

```
@ECHO ON
@CD C:\Users\%username%\Pictures

For /r %%A In (*.jpg *.jpeg) Do ren "%%A" "*.png"
goto :eof
```